# How many objects have the same attribute value?

Tags: ruby, enumerable

I have an array of objects with top and left attributes like this:

```
[{top: 30, left: 20}, {top:50, left:10}, {..}]
```

I am trying to find how many objects have the *approximate same top value*. In this case:

```
[{top: 10, left: 20}, {top:10, left:10}, {top: 10, left: 123},
{top:500, left:10}, {top:2, left: 50}, {top:2, left:400}]
```

the method would return `5` because there are three objects that have `10` as top value and two objects that have `2` as top value. If there is an object that doesn't share its top value with anything else, it is not taken into account. I am not looking for exact values, but with a flexibility of a 10% of difference on the values so that `{top:10, left:20}` and `{top:10.13, left:20}` would be considered as having the same top. So far, I have this:

```
myarr.group_by { |x| x[:top] }.map { |k,v| [k, v.length] }.to_h
```

but this would not take into account this margin error. I am not sure how I would change it in order to do so.

Comment: Let's say your margin is `2` (absolute), what are you going to do with `[10, 11, 12, 13, 14]`? `12+/-2`? `10+/-2` and `14+/-2`? `10` and `13+/-2`?

Comment: How does `10.13` fit within 10% difference of `10`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how you want to express "similar", you could do something like this:

```
def count_similar(a, lower_bound, upper_bound)
  a.count { |h| h[:top] >= lower_bound && h[:top] <= upper_bound }
end

a = [{top: 10, left: 20}, {top:10, left:10}, {top: 10, left: 123},
     {top:500, left:10} , {top:2, left: 50}, {top:2, left:400}]

count_similar(a, 1, 19) #=> 5
```

Comment: I was thinking in similarity in terms of how similar is one from the other one. So, is one is just 10% bigger or smaller than the other one, that could be considered the same value. I can't rely on static bounds, because the top values can range from 10000 to 50. I don't have control on that.

Comment: I wasn't advocating "static bounds".  Since you didn't provide a definition of "similar" I just gave this as a possible basic structure for counting elements for which the value for `:top` falls within a range. You might do some other calculations to compute what you want the upper and lower bounds to be.  For example you could make the upper bound 10% higher than the mean or median or whatever, possibly after throwing out some values that you regard as "outliers", based on some criterion.  That's entirely up to you.